# Magento Collect Rates All Items is empty

Tags: magento2

I'm using magento 2.4.6

In CollectRates() i'm trying to get all products in the Cart.

But AllItems is empty.

```
$this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES'. json_encode($request->getAllItems()));
```

and I get

```
[2023-11-15T22:19:03.165802+00:00] main.INFO: COLLECT RATES[{}] [] []
```

What i'm doing wrong?

thanks

Update:

If I try with use `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` and

```
    $this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 1 '. json_encode($this->_quote->getAllVisibleItems()));
    $this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 2 '. json_encode($this->_quote->getAllItems()));
    $this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 3 '. json_encode($this->_quote->getData()));
    $this->_logger->info('COLLECT RATES 4 '. json_encode($this->_quote->getCustomer()));
```

output:

```
[2023-11-15T22:28:07.383010+00:00] main.INFO: COLLECT RATES 1 [] [] []
[2023-11-15T22:28:07.383132+00:00] main.INFO: COLLECT RATES 2 [] [] []
[2023-11-15T22:28:07.383220+00:00] main.INFO: COLLECT RATES 3 [] [] []
[2023-11-15T22:28:07.383301+00:00] main.INFO: COLLECT RATES 4 {} [] []
```